# Why this bash script does not work the same for me as when I run it in the console?

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to migrate some repositories from one Azure organization to another. So write a bash script to do it, here's the part I'm having trouble with:

```
#! /bin/sh
declare -a Repos=('old_name,new_name')
OLD_ORGANIZATION="foo"
OLD_PROJECT="as244"
OLD_PAT="any_access_token"
IFS=','
for val in "${Repos[@]}"; do
  read -a repos <<< "$val"
  echo $val
  echo ${repos[0]}
  echo ${repos[1]}
  git clone "https://$OLD_PAT@dev.azure.com/$OLD_ORGANIZATION/$OLD_PROJECT/_git/${repos[0]}"
  cd ${repos[0]} 
  git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
  git branch -a
done
```

But I get the following error:

```
remote: Found 76 objects to send. (39 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (76/76), 232.12 KiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
fatal: '  origin/develop' is not a valid branch name.
fatal: '  origin/main' is not a valid branch name.
fatal: '  origin/stable-paths' is not a valid branch name.
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/stable-paths
```

However when from my console I do the git clone and then run:

```
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
```

(the same script command), I don't get any errors and I manage to clean up the branch names to something like:
add-title-button
adjustment-button-bars
back-list-button

(without remotes/origin/)

What is happening? Why does it behave differently in my script? I can't run it one by one since there are more than 100 repositories

UPDATE:

```
#!/bin/bash
for val in "${Repos[@]}"; do
  first=${val%%,*}
  second=${val#*,}
  echo "Original value: $val"
  echo "First part: $first"
  echo "Second part: $second"
  git clone "https://$OLD_PAT@dev.azure.com/$OLD_ORGANIZATION/$OLD_PROJECT/_git/$first"
  cd $first
  git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read -r remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
  git branch -a
```

Output:

```
Unpacking objects: 100% (76/76), 232.12 KiB | 457.00 KiB/s, done.
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.
fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists.
Branch 'stable-paths' set up to track remote branch 'stable-paths' from 'origin'.
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Quotes, quotes, quotes ...

Comment: I get this warning on that line: ^-- SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes. I put the -r but it doesn't work, do you have any idea what else it could be?

Comment: Just to start, you're using `/bin/sh` while using bash extensions. To reliably get bash extensions you need to use `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: And immediately, you're not trimming whitespace from your branch names. A branch named `'origin/main'` can't be accurately addressed as `'  origin/main'`.

Comment: And if you want to split your `a,b` pairs into `a` and `b`, `read -a` is serious overkill. `first=${var%%,*}` and `second=${var#*,}` and there you are. Heck, `IFS=, read -r a b` and there you are.

Comment: The `git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed` pipeline... I can't understand what you meant it to accomplish, so I don't know where to start. In general, though: Don't ever try to parse git output meant for human readers. Git has separate commands (the "plumbing") that are meant for programs to parse; use those instead of the "chrome" commands that produce output for humans and then you don't need to munge human-readable output into machine-readable output in the first place. (The machine-readable output is also much more stable between releases/configurations/etc)

Comment: Also, you're clearly ignoring a bunch of other shellcheck warnings if the only thing you get out of it is SC2162.

Comment: I think the error is in the white spaces. Could you help me remove them? With grep -v '\->' I try to exclude the line showing the current branch. Thanks for the other recommendations, this is actually my first time writing bash scripts.

Comment: When you set `IFS=','` globally (rather than e.g. as a prefix to `read` like in Charles Duffy's suggestion), it tends to affect a lot of things you don't expect or want. In this case, it looks like it's preventing the `read remote` from trimming leading whitespace from the branch names. Try making the assignment to `IFS` a prefix to the `read` it should apply to, and make sure it's not being set to weird values anywhere else in either. BTW, if you're actually going to have this act on more than one repo, you should `cd` back out of the repo directory after working on it.

Comment: Some great suggestions there, but I'm curious why you aren't using `git clone --mirror`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have followed your recommendations and removed the IFS=',' (The new code is seen under UPDATE in the question) and the whitespace error was fixed but now I get a new error, could you help me?

Comment: You ought to be able to figure that out.   `git clone` automatically creates a `main` branch.  You need to check for that and skip creating a branch that already exists.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Thanks to everyone's help, I was able to migrate all 100 repositories!